# Diferença entre id e class no HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Quando eu tenho que usar "id" e quando tenho que usar "class" no HTML5?

Comment: Olá Gabriel, bem-vindo! Marquei a pergunta como duplicada pois acho que a resposta à tua pergunta está nas respostas dessa outra. Se achares que há dados que faltam para o que procuras diz ou abre uma nova pergunta mais específica.